# Use case diagram agriculture project

Tags: uml, staruml

[image][![ ][2]][2]

Here's the flow of my project-
  1. User logs into the system providing Username and password, which is authenticated by the Server with help of the Database
2. After authentication, User ie. Farmer will be able to Start water sprinkler's Motor or
 Star Pesticide sprinkler motor or 
Start camera to monitor his farm or
 Schedule the Water pump/Pesticide motor for future time. 
 3. Now Server, Water Motor, Pesticide sprinkler, Camera nor Micro controller are Humans, so Is the diagram correct to represent them as Actors? Or what is the right way to represent them? What corrections do I make?

Comment: Is it correct to show Server, Camera, Motor or Pesticide bottle as Actors? Or is there some other way to represent non human components?

Comment: Our lecturer taught us, that some times you can use rectangular to represent non human actors ex-inventory systems, I think your diagram looks fine

Comment: Yes there is some Blockhead symbol right? Unfortunately StarUml has no such a thing, that's why the confusion.

Comment: Here's the slides of our lecturer http://imgur.com/a/SEyLs

Comment: Thank man , big help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `Login` is no use case at all. It is a constraint you can apply to other UCs. Remove it.
2. Generalizing UCs is a bad idea. Each UC needs to describe a separate added value the system returns to the actors. I also doubt that `Motor on/off` is a UC. Rather `{ motor must be on }` is a constraint you can apply to other UCs.
3. Remove the `<<includes>>` in `Supply pesticides`. You are using them as functional decomposition. Rather rename the UC as to what it's meant to be: `Reduce insect attack`. Then the application of pesticides is a result of doing the actions inside the UC.
4. `Online streaming` is no meaningful UC. Think about what you are streaming and express that in the name of the UC (e.g. `Stream <whatever is so nice to be streamed>`).
5. Similarly `Scheduling`. Tell the reader what you schedule (so he get's an idea of the why and the goal behind).
6. `Logout` is as much as UC as `Login`. Remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the necessary changes, And Do I keep Server, Motor , Pesticide bottle, Camera and Microcontroller as Actors ? Or should the use case must only be about User interaction?

Comment: Yep. It's a bit strange indeed to show machines as stickmen. But that's how it's done in standard UML (the word actor is taken in its original sense as person acting, but today machines do that more often than humans). You are free to invent your own images. Stereotype your class (e.g. as <<machine>> or whatever) and assign an image. You shouldn't overdo this as it might end up in Powerpoint slides rather than UML diagrams.

Comment: Thanks :) describing the Stereotype for non human components made sense, thanks a lot for all of your advice :)